# E0401:Unable to import 'flask'

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

Am new in flask development and trying to import flask in my project but `Pylint` is giving this error in **VSCode** `E0401:Unable to import 'flask'`, but I installed flask already in my project but I don't know how to solve this,  how can I resolve it.

My virtual environment is installed , and the image which proves is below:

[image]

The error am getting code , the underlined from:
[image]

what am I missing?

Comment: are you using a virtualenv ?

Comment: yes I am using it too I installed it , maybe theres a way of checking it if its installed

Comment: @Derlin, when I instll it again they say `Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\hpa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (16.0.0)` which shows its already there

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 36):

Solution is to switch Interpreter

**Simple solution :**

Go to command palette
**Type--**  Python:Select Interpreter

Select  virtual environment that you  created

answered specifically for vscode can work for other also .

Comment: This worked for me. I was following the [gcp Flask tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/writing-web-service) and received the same error. On my system (macOS) I had to type `>Python:` to display a list of python commands, then select `Set Interpreter`

Comment: Also need to restart the VS Code terminal to pick that up!

Comment: To expand on "Select virtual environment that you created": I had to browse to `venv/Scripts/python.exe` (on Windows).

Answer (score 16):

Go to Command Palette using `Ctrl + Shift + P`.
select `python:select interpreter` and then choose your appropriate virtualenv.

Answer (score 10):

I guess VS Code doesn't use the correct virtualenv.

To select a virtualenv using the GUI, see [Configuring Python environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

If you use the terminal and have `code` in your path, launch VS code from your workspace and the virtualenv will be loaded automatically:

```
cd python-workspace
code -n python-workspace
```

(note: the `-n` is for *new window*)

If this does not work, ensure that `pylint` is installed *in your virtualenv* (i.e. your are not using the global `pylint`). If it still does not work, have a look at [this troubleshooting guide](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/troubleshooting_linting/).

Comment: I edited my post , that's what I see as my virtual env

Comment: Also need to restart the VS Code terminal to pick that up!

Answer (score 4):

Due to the fact that you are using a virtual environment, first of all it's required that Pylint is installed *inside* this virtual env.

Furthermore, you need to add the following entry to your **workspace settings** to avoid the `[pylint] E0401` error:

```python
"python.linting.pylintPath": "/path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/pylint"
```

This overrides the user settings (global settings) and instructs VSCode to use the Pylint version *within your virtual env* (instead of the *global* one). That was probably the point you was missing ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem when I code in VS code.

I open Command Palette by ⇧⌘P.  And run the linter to solve this problem like this picture.

[image]

Here is [the document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_run-linting) from VS code.

Answer (score 1):

The python extension picks up the venv automatically, *and* activates it for new terminals panes:
[image: Select Interpreter already selects ./venv/bin/python by default]

So selecting interpreter is not the issue. The only way I can get this to work is to install `pylint` into the user path after activating the *venv*:

```
./venv/bin/pip install -U pylint
```

*How* this works to solve the **E0401** I got in VSCode, don't ask me, I can't explain it. Feels like cheating. I thought the point of using virtualenvs was so that we could avoid having to deal with ambiguities across system/site/user modules.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the vscode cannot run the lint becouse my flask install with venv environment, so I deactivate the vent and install flask again in the normal environment , the lint will be work~

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the command

**sudo apt install python3-flask**

Answer (score 0):

You can just install **pylint** in your virtualenv using

```
pip install pylint
```

(inside your terminal) and restart  your VS code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have created a `.pylintrc` file at the root of your project.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I have disabled pylint. and it works

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command pallet in VSCode and type `python select linter`, then you can disable the linter there.