# pylint false positive E0401 import errors in vscode while using venv

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, pylint, python-venv

I created a venv using python3.6 on my mac os in this folder
`/Users/kim/Documents/Apps/PythonApps/python36-miros-a3`

I ran a `pip install pylint` after I activated the virtual env

My workspace is in `/Users/kim/Documents/Apps/WebApps/miros-a3`

Inside my vscode workspace, I have the following Workspace settings

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python.pythonPath": "/Users/kim/Documents/Apps/PythonApps/python36-miros-a3/bin/python3.6",
        "python.venvPath": "/Users/kim/Documents/Apps/PythonApps"
    }
}
```

I have tried setting a custom path for the pylint and also changing the venvpath.

The pylint kept complaining about the import statement saying it does not exist.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, they are in the same folder, and I can definitely execute my python files.

What can I do to avoid these kind of false positive import errors?

I have also tried the following:

1. go to commandline turn on the virtual env and then type `code` to activate the vscode as recommended here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac
2. also tried this https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/troubleshooting_linting/

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Pylint has some quirks. In this case it doesn't know where to find your module because it's in subdirectory of your venv path. To solve this:

1. Put this setting in your workspace or folder settings:

   ```
   "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
       "--init-hook",
       "import sys; sys.path.append('<path to folder your module is in>')"
   ]
   ```

   or, maybe better
2. Generate .pylintrc file. From integrated terminal with venv activated run:

   ```
   pylint --generate-rcfile > .pylintrc
   ```

   then open the generated file and uncomment the **init-hook=** part to be:

   ```
   init-hook='import sys; sys.path.append("<path to folder you module is in>")'
   ```

   Read the *.pylintrc* and tweak settings if you wish. In both cases path should point to your 'database' folder.
3. After learning about pylint settings, do it the right way:

   ```
   from database.database_dispatcher import ...
   ```

   See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51095449/pylint-false-positive-e0401-import-errors-in-vscode-while-using-venv/51236340#51236340) by Anthony Sottile.

Comment: I much prefer the first approach, because it will work on any system by using `{workspaceFolder}`: `"import sys; sys.path.append({workspaceFolder})"`

Answer (score 13):

To me, `pylint` is correct in flagging this error here

the top level module is `database` (it contains an `__init__.py` file)

Your import should look like (fully absolute)

```
from database.database_dispatcher import ...
```

or (explicit relative) (yes! the `.` before the module name is intentional)

```
from .database_dispatcher import ...
```

My follow-up guess is that you're currently invoking your script as `python ./database/main.py ...` which is putting `./database` at the beginning of `sys.path` so it  would *appear* that your imports are working correctly -- this is side-stepping your module structure however.  You should be invoking your script using `python -m database.main ...` instead.

Note that *implicit relative* imports were removed in python 3.x -- though this (imo) wart of script `sys.path` insertion remains.

Answer (score 7):

Just my $0.02 on how I fixed it in my situation.

My problem was totally related to having pylint installed globally, and coding in a venv. vscode was trying to use the globally installed pylint which simply was not aware of dependencies I installed in my Python venv.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50905745/149154) solved my problem. It points [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) which explained how to configure vscode to run using the venv for my project. Once i did that vscode immediately threw a warning saying I had no linting tool installed and prompted me to install one. Once that was done my linting false-positives went away.

Comment: I like this solution, but the only problem is that pylint will be in the requirement file. I'm ok with it tho.

Comment: @ericDaWang You can create a separate `requirements-dev.txt` and put `pylint` and other development-only packages in there.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Gatmando's answer, you need to tell vscode to use the pylint in your `.env` instead of the global pylint:

In your workspace settings file: `.vscode/settings.json`, add `python.linting.pylintPath` and point it to `pylint` package in your `virtualenv`:

```json
{
    "python.pythonPath": ".env/bin/python",
    "python.linting.pylintPath": ".env/bin/pylint"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to create a [`.env` file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variable-definitions-file) in the vscode project root dir:

`.env` file:

```
PYTHONPATH=.
```

Some caveats of using the `.env` file:

- It will be used for anything that the vscode ide runs (e.g. pylint, pytest), so the `PYTHONPATH` may clash between different tools.
- You could specify multiple dirs to `PYTHONPATH` to accommodate multiple tools by using separators. (Example: `PYTHONPATH=src:.` ) However, this is not cross-OS because the Windows separator is `;` while Linux/Mac is `:`

---

If the `.env` `PYTHONPATH` solves your issue, then great. But due to the  caveats, I ended up using the `pylint --init-hook` method because it only affects `pylint`, and it can be cross-OS:

`.vscode/settings.json`

```json
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--init-hook",
        "import sys, os; sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join('src', 'foo'))"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

## add library to PYTHONPATH

When executing pylint from `bash` you can do this:

```bash
PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:library_path" pylint project_path
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is likely to affect first-time VS Code Pylint extension users. To solve it, check if you have your own `pylint` package by running:

```
pip show pylint
```

(or `conda list pylint`).

...and if not, then install your own `pylint` for the desired Python version (in the `conda` environment of your choice, etc.), e.g. by:

```
pip install pylint
```

(or `conda install -c conda-forge pylint`).

and now the VS Code Pylint extension will automatically switch to this version of `pylint` (after Python kernel restart in VS Code) and use this `pylint` package (and your Python kernel) instead of its own unreachable bundled-in one (and the system Python).

---

This can happen by default in a fresh environment (such as a data science container) because the Pylint VS Code extension ([Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.pylint) | [Open VSX](https://open-vsx.org/extension/ms-python/pylint)) has `pylint` bundled in, in a deeply nested, hard-to-find location, and likely matching your Linux system built-in python rather than your desired up-to-date one. So if you choose your desired Python kernel, it will (by default) not contain the `pylint` package and the bundled-in one will likely be unreachable from your selected Python kernel (`conda` environment).

Comment: I know what you are thinking Mods, but no, I genuinely wrote it all by myself. But having read it now I am almost sure the now banned AI detectors would give you a false positive here and with great confidence;)