# Python Intellisense VSCode Wrong Autocomplete Imports & PyLint wrong impor-error warning

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

My current app structure is:

```
backend
  -- api
    |-- migrations
    |-- app
    |   -- main
    |      -- routes.py
    |   -- modules
    |      -- Mod1
    |         -- helper.py
    |         -- controller.py
    |      -- Mod2
    |         -- helper.py
    |         -- controller.py
    |-- venv
    |-- application.py
```

My settings (saved in `.vscode` within the `backend` folder):

```
    "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/api/venv/bin/python3",
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/api/.env",
    "python.venvPath": "${workspaceFolder}/api/venv/bin/python3",
```

If I try to import a module, I would normally do `from app.modules.mod1 import controller`. But VSCode Intellisense keeps correcting me to `from api.app.modules...` - which doesn't work (Flask gives me an Import Error).

Pylint also keeps telling me that my imports are wrong, even though my app runs fine. I adjusted the `pylint-path` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51236213/8930321) answer, but still gives me the same error.

I also lost the ability to "navigate" my code - I can't hold Cmd and click a function. Any ideas on what I might me doing wrong? It's a tremendous lost in productivity to miss the autocomplete and function links...

Answer (score 0):

For further reference, the developers on Python Language (VSCode) answered my question, I needed to add:

```
{
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./api"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the same boat and I needed two settings to make this work:

```
{
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./api"],
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./api"]
}
```