# pylint: unable to import conda installed modules

Tags: python, anaconda, pylint

I have a package I'm developing in a Conda virtual environment that runs fine and imports all my installed modules as needed. I'm trying to use a pylint git pre-commit hook, but getting E0401 import-errors for installed modules (e.g., Pandas). I've tried several [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899436/pylint-unable-to-import-error-how-to-set-pythonpath?rq=1) to edit my path via the .pylintrc `init-hook` option with no luck. I can add the direct path to my conda environment's site-packages folder, but that of course doesn't work for other collaborators. pylint is installed in the conda environment. I'm using the command line to run pylint.

How do I use `pylint` with a conda virtual environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pylint false positive E0401 import errors in vscode while using venv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51095449/pylint-false-positive-e0401-import-errors-in-vscode-while-using-venv)

Comment: Thanks, but no, that is about getting pylint in VS to recognize modules within the package being developed. I'm not using VS or having problems with modules internal to my package.

Comment: Can you provide your pylint and astroid versions ?

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas pylint version is 2.12.2 and astroid is 2.9.0

Answer (score 0):

I haven't discovered why, but I have found that when using `pylint` inside of a conda environment,

```
pylint myfile.py
```

has import errors on things like pandas and torch.  However, it seems to work when I do

```
python -m pylint myfile.py
```

I believe `pylint` used by itself is using the python from conda (since pylint is also in conda and the environment is activated).  However, I have not yet found why the former fails and the latter works.

I hope this helps you and others coming here.